# How to get AS/400 macro to pull data from Excel

Tags: excel, ibm-midrange

Hello I’m trying to create a macro on the AS/400 that will pull data from an Excel sheet and input data to the screen. I know how to create a macro to run the menu option by using the record macro button but not sure how to get it to access the excel file so it will run through the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are recording a VBScript macro for Client Access, you'll need to connect to the spreadsheet with ADODB or something similar.  [This page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_databases_excel.php) has an example.  Basic idea:

```
CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                  myXlsFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;" & _
                  strHeader & """"
CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
' do something with Fields(i).Value
MoveNext
Close both objects
```